# Why when i rotate a character with transform.forward it moves character AND rotate when i only want to rotate it cause it already have moving mechanic

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

## Whole code

**Please try to help im just starting out with unity**

```
   Vector2 inputVector = new Vector2(0,0);

inputVector = inputVector.normalized;

Vector3 moveDir = new Vector3(inputVector.x, 0f, inputVector.y);

transform.position += moveDir * normalSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

float rotateSpeed = 10f;
transform.forward = Vector3.Slerp(transform.forward, moveDir, Time.deltaTime * rotateSpeed);

}
}
```

Thanks for all of the help

Comment: You're modifying `transform.position` in this code. Are you saying that your character is moving even if you remove that line?

Comment: yea i just deleted line "transform.position += moveDir * normalSpeed * Time.deltaTime;" and character is somehow moving like drifitng or smth like this

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just lerp a vector. You need to keep track of a running position and rotation, then build the matrix from those inputs. Do not attempt to modify just a single dimension of a matrix or you get a non-orthogonal matrix. All of those vectors are suppose to be of unit length.